# Объединение полей Entity через Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Есть энтити объект

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "votes")
public class Vote extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public Vote() {
    }

    public Vote(User user, Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.user = user;
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

Я использую Spring Data Repository, у меня уже есть метод для подсчета количества голосов по каждому ресторану

```
@Repository
public interface VoteRepository extends CrudRepository<Vote, Integer> {

    Integer countByRestaurantId(Integer restaurantId);
}
```

И сейчас я хочу добавить возможность просмотра статистики голосов по датам. Как вариант - я могу передавать `Map <LocalDate, Integer>`, где значение - количество голосов по дате(ключу):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ADMIN_VOTES_URL, produces = JSON_TYPE)
public class AdminVoteController implements Controller {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private VoteService voteService;

    @GetMapping("/statistics")
    public Map<LocalDate, Integer> getVoteStatistics(@PathVariable Integer restaurantId) {
        log.info("get count of the votes for restaurant {}", restaurantId);
        return voteService.getVoteStatistic(restaurantId);
    }
}
```

Моя неудавшаяся попытка обратиться в репозиторий выглядит так:

```
@Query("select distinct v.date, count(v.id) from Vote v where v.restaurant.id = ?1 group by v.date")
    Map<LocalDate, Integer> findAllByDateAndRestaurantId(Integer restaurantId);
```

Как мне это сделать при помощи Spring Data? Либо если можно как-то по-другому - буду рад любому совету, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Создайте кастомный репозиторий

```
public interface StatisticVotesRepository {
     Map<LocalDate, Integer> findAllByDateAndRestaurantId(Integer restaurantId);
}
```

Создаете его реализацию

```
public class StatisticVotesRepositoryImpl implements StatisticVotesRepository {

private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
public StatisticVotesRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Override
public Map<LocalDate, Integer> findAllByDateAndRestaurantId(Integer restaurantId) {
    ...
    entityManager.createNativeQuery(
       "select distinct v.date, count(v.id) from Vote v where v.restaurant.id = :pRestaurantId group by v.date")
                 .setParameter("pRestaurantId", restaurantId);

    ...

}

}
```

наследуете его вашим репозиторием

```
@Repository
public interface VoteRepository extends CrudRepository<Vote, Integer>, StatisticVotesRepository {
    Integer countByRestaurantId(Integer restaurantId);
}
```

и добавьте новый репозиторий в конфигурацию в аннотацию @EnableJpaRepositories, например так

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "youPackage", repositoryImplementationPostfix = "RepositoryImpl")
```

Comment: @Override
public Map<LocalDate, Integer> findAllByDateAndRestaurantId(Integer restaurantId)

не совсем пойму - что прописывать внутри метода вместо троеточий

Comment: Добавил внизу более простое решение, через ДТО.

Comment: Но без Вас я бы не справился - именно Вы натолкнули на мысль, так что огромное спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле - нашлось более простое решение.

1) Создал ДТО:

```
public class VoteTo implements Serializable {

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date;

    private Long count;

    public VoteTo() {
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public VoteTo(LocalDate date, Long count) {
        this.date = date;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

2) Создал в том же репозитории метод, прямо обращающийся к конструктору:

```
@Query("select new ru.topjava.graduation.model.dto.VoteTo(v.date, count(v.id)) from Vote v " +
" where v.restaurant.id = ?1 group by v.date")
List<VoteTo> groupCountByData(Integer restaurantId);
```